# Multiplying character-separated numbers in a cell with another cell (Distributive Property)

Tags: google-sheets

I have numbers in one cell that are separated by "-" and I want to multiply them by another number in another cell.

Example:

A: 12 - 6 - 8

B: 83

Doing MULTIPLY(SUM(SPLIT(A,"-")),B) is not mathematically correct. How can I do 12 * 83 + 8 * 83 + 8 * 83?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(ζ,JOIN("-",ζ*SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(ζ))))(SPLIT(A1,"-")))
```

#### Update

```
=PRODUCT(SPLIT(A1,"-"))
```

#### Update 2

Let's say you have `83` in B1 and `12 - 6 - 8` in A1. Here's what you can try:

```
=LAMBDA(ζ,SUMPRODUCT(ζ,IF(ζ,B1)))(SPLIT(A1,"-"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. All it did was return the same values without spaces though. Like this: Origin cell = "10 - 2 - 6", Your formula result = "10-2-6"

Comment: are you sure it results in 10-2-6? I just tried it and it results in 10-4-18 which is 10*1-2*2-6*3.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. The expected result for "10-2-6" is "120". So, 10*2*6. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the formula. You should update your question as well because the provided link is not really what you are asking for.

Comment: You are completely right and I'm ashamed of myself for not finding out the SPLIT() by myself and for not understanding the question I had linked myself. Thank you.

Comment: I've modified the question altogether. I hope you can still help with it and edit your answer. Leaving the question on how to split numbers separated by hyphens seemed way to simple and I couldn't delete the question because you had already given an answer. So I decided to edit it and spice it up. Thanks again.